# Sublime Video: Playlist which gets all attached videos

Tags: code

I searched a way to automatically load all attached videos in a custom post type as SublimeVideo playlist. After some time I got it working and here I'll share the code with everyone who is interested to do it the same way.

Comment: Philipp, it is ok to ask and answer your own Question. Right now, this one is hanging on the *unanswered* list, when in fact it is not ;)

Comment: You're right @brasofilio. Hopefully it's OK how I closed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get all video attachements of the post or page:

```
<?php $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'video') );

if ( $attachments ) { ?>
```

2nd: Load the videos into the playlist code with a unique ID (http://docs.sublimevideo.net/beta/playlists). Here I do use the attachement ID for each video and of cause the same for the thumbnail. You have to change the width and height within the `<video>` code.

```
<div id="playlist1" class='sv_playlist'>
<?php   
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'video',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'post_status' => null,
     'orderby' => 'title',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);

if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo '<div class="video_wrap">';
        echo '<video width="568" height="320" id="video';
        echo $attachment->ID;
        echo '" data-settings="autoresize:fit" poster="';
        echo '" preload="true">';
        echo '<source src="';
        echo wp_get_attachment_url ($attachment->ID);
        echo '" /></video>';
        echo '</div>';



    }
}?>
<ul class='thumbs'>
<?php   
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'video',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'post_status' => null,
     'orderby' => 'title',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);

if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo '<li style="padding:0px;" id="thumbnail_video';
        echo $attachment->ID;
        echo '">  <a href=" "> <img style="height:100%" alt="" src="';
        echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
        echo '" width="144" height="71" /> <span class="play" /> </a> </li>';

}
} 

?>
</ul>
</div>
```

3rd: Well that's done. Now I wanted to have the videos responsive to allow resizing it for mobile devices. Here the SublimeVideo-Team helped me. Please add the following style to your stylesheet:

```
 /* VIDEO PLAYER!! */

/* Thumbnails below the video */

img {border:none;}

.sv_playlist .video_wrap {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display:none;
background:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,23,60,0.5) 0 4px 17px;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,23,60,0.5) 0 4px 17px;
box-shadow:rgba(0,23,60,0.5) 0 4px 17px;
}


.sv_playlist .video_wrap.active {
  display:block;
}

.sv_playlist ul.thumbs {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:800px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:20px auto;
}

.sv_playlist li {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  width:144px;
  height:81px;
  margin:0 19px 19px 0;
  background:#000;
  border:1px solid #000;
  -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,23,60,0.5) 0 2px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,23,60,0.5) 0 2px 10px;
  box-shadow:rgba(0,23,60,0.5) 0 2px 10px;
}

.sv_playlist li.active {
  border-color:#fff;
}

.sv_playlist li a {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

.sv_playlist li a span.play {
  display:block;
  width:144px;
  height:81px;
  /* you can find the play icon here: http://f.cl.ly/items/3M0u0p0i0k1l3S0v2b1G/playlist_play_icon.png */
  background:url('http://f.cl.ly/items/3M0u0p0i0k1l3S0v2b1G/playlist_play_icon.png') no-repeat center;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0 1px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow:inset rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0 1px 0;
  -o-transition:background-color,0.25s,linear;
  -moz-transition:background-color,0.25s,linear;
  -webkit-transition:background-color,0.25s,linear;
  transition:background-color,0.25s,linear;
}

.sv_playlist li a:hover span.play {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.sv_playlist li.active a span.play {
  background:none;
}
```

The fluid width is defined here (you copied it already!):

```
.sv_playlist .video_wrap {
width: 100%;
height: auto; }
```

Last but not least: Add the JavaScript code as seen at the documentation (http://docs.sublimevideo.net/beta/playlists):

```
<script> 
/** http://docs.sublimevideo.net/playlists **/
/** jQuery version **/

var SublimeVideo = SublimeVideo || { playlists: {} };

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // A SublimeVideoPlaylist instance can takes some options:
  //  - autoplayOnPageLoad: whether or not to autoplay the playlist on page load. Note that if you set it to true,
  //    you should remove the 'sublime' class from the first video in the playlist.
  //  - loadNext: whether or not to load the next item in the playlist once a video playback ends
  //  - autoplayNext: whether or not to autoplay the next item in the playlist once a video playback ends
  //  - loop: whether or not to loop the entire playlist once the last video playback ends
  var playlistOptions = { autoplayOnPageLoad: false, loadNext: true, autoplayNext: true, loop: false };

  // Automatically instantiate all the playlists in the page
  jQuery('.sv_playlist').each(function(i, el) {
    SublimeVideo.playlists[el.id] = new SublimeVideoPlaylist(el.id, playlistOptions);
  });
});

var SublimeVideoPlaylist = function(playlistWrapperId, options){
  if (!jQuery("#" + playlistWrapperId)) return;

  this.options = options;
  this.playlistWrapperId = playlistWrapperId;
  this.firstVideoId = jQuery("#" + this.playlistWrapperId + " video").attr("");

  this.setupObservers();
  this.updateActiveVideo(this.firstVideoId);
};

jQuery.extend(SublimeVideoPlaylist.prototype, {
  setupObservers: function() {
    var that = this;

    jQuery("#"+ this.playlistWrapperId + " li").each(function() {
      jQuery(this).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("active")) {
          that.clickOnThumbnail(jQuery(this).attr("id"), that.options['autoplayNext']);
        }
      });
    });
  },
  reset: function() {
    // Hide the current active video
    jQuery("#" + this.playlistWrapperId + " .video_wrap.active").removeClass("active");

    // Get current active video and unprepare it
    // we could have called sublimevideo.unprepare() without any arguments, but this is faster
    sublimevideo.unprepare(jQuery("#" + this.activeVideoId)[0]);

    // Deselect its thumbnail
    this.deselectThumbnail(this.activeVideoId);
  },
  clickOnThumbnail: function(thumbnailId, autoplay) {
    this.updateActiveVideo(thumbnailId.replace(/^thumbnail_/, ""));

    if (autoplay) { // And finally, prepare and play it if autoplay is true
      sublimevideo.prepareAndPlay(jQuery("#" + this.activeVideoId)[0]);
    } else { // Or only prepare it if autoplay is false
      sublimevideo.prepare(jQuery("#" + this.activeVideoId)[0]);
    }
  },
  selectThumbnail: function(videoId) {
    jQuery("#thumbnail_" + videoId).addClass("active");
  },
  deselectThumbnail: function(videoId) {
    jQuery("#thumbnail_" + videoId).removeClass("active");
  },
  updateActiveVideo: function(videoId) {
    // Basically undo all the stuff and bring it back to the point before js kicked in
    if (this.activeVideoId) this.reset();

    // Set the new active video
    this.activeVideoId = videoId;

    // And show the video
    this.showActiveVideo();
  },
  showActiveVideo: function() {
    // Select its thumbnail
    this.selectThumbnail(this.activeVideoId);

    // Show it
    jQuery("#" + this.activeVideoId).parent().addClass("active");
  },
  handleAutoNext: function(newVideoId) {
    this.clickOnThumbnail(newVideoId, this.options['autoplayNext']);
  }
});

sublimevideo.ready(function() {
  for (var playlistId in SublimeVideo.playlists) {
    SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].clickOnThumbnail(SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].activeVideoId, SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].options['autoplayOnPageLoad']);
  }

  sublimevideo.onEnd(function(sv) {
    var matches = sv.element.id.match(/^video([0-9]+)$/);
    if (matches !== undefined) {
      var playlistId    = jQuery(sv.element).parents('.sv_playlist').attr("id");
      var nextThumbnail = jQuery("#thumbnail_" + sv.element.id).next("li");

      if (nextThumbnail.length > 0) {
        if (SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].options['loadNext']) {
          SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].handleAutoNext(nextThumbnail.attr("id"));
        }
      }
      else if (SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].options['loop']) {
        SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].updateActiveVideo(SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].firstVideoId);
        SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].handleAutoNext(SublimeVideo.playlists[playlistId].activeVideoId);
      }
      else { sublimevideo.stop(); }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

That's it. I hope it helps anyone who starts get get lost with this, too!

Comment: It would be better if you edited your question, cut the solution content out, and paste it into your answer.